# Javascript: Back-Referencing in Regex without remembering last match

Tags: javascript, regex, grouping, backreference

Is there any thing that doesn't remember the last Matched value in back referencing ?

```
(abc|def)=\1 matches abc=abc or def=def, but not abc=def or def=abc.
```

In a string i need to match a pattern that matches **abc=def** or **def=abc** with back-referencing. But i can match only *abc=abc* or *def=def*.

I can do it with regex pattern like `(abc|def)=(abc|def)`.This matches all the cases like **abc=abc, def=def, abc=def, def=abc**

In my case abc or def is a very long thing to search and if i have to change the regex i have to change in both the places. Is there any way to back-reference to the group without remembrance ?

https://regex101.com/r/bL9wU1/1

Comment: Dont think it is possible coz you want to backreference without actually capturing it.

Comment: If you have to repeat parts of the regex, maybe regex is just the wrong tool for the job. Have you considered parsing it on a different level, like `input.split("=").map(part => part.match(/abc|def/))`?

Comment: You cannot use back references for this task. Instead, build your regex dynamically using variables in a RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use back references for this task.

> Backreferences **match the same *text*** as previously matched by a capturing group.

That is, they do not use the same *pattern* defined in a capturing group.

A workaround is to build a dynamic regex pattern with blocks and use a RegExp constructor:

```js
var ss = [ "abc=abc", "def=def", "abc=def", "def=abc"]; // Test strings
 
var block = "(?:abc|def)";                             // Define the pattern block
var rx = RegExp(block + "=" + block);                  // Build the regex dynamically
document.body.innerHTML += "Pattern: <b>" + rx.source
          + "</b><br/>";                               // Display resulting pattern
for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) {                  // Demo
  document.body.innerHTML += "Testing \"<i>" + ss[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  document.body.innerHTML += "Matched: <b>" + rx.test(ss[s]) + "</b><br/>";
}
```